# search and replace string with special characters in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, replace

I am using mongodb 2.4 with cakephp and as there is no direct way to search and replace string in array in mongo. I am looping through all records and using str_replace to  replace string with special charcaters('/','+','-') etc. But it is not working if more than one special charcter appears in a string. Kindly help me out in using str_replace or another way to find and replace in mongo

Comment: can you provide an example of the case when it's not working?

Comment: like there is a string "Fixing-Technology/Multiple time-Rebase". here it does not work

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using regex,

```
<?php
    echo preg_replace('/(\/|\+|-)+/i', ' ', $string);
?>
```